# HTML/CSS: stretching height <div> layout

Tags: css, html, height, stretching

```
<div style="width: 800px; height: 600px"> 
    <div style="height: 100px"> 
        top fixed-height row
    </div> 
    <div style="???"> 
        bottom stretching row (the height should be 500px in this case.) 
    </div> 
</div>
```

What's the standard way to create two-row layout without javascript where the top one is fixed-size and the bottom one stretches and fits to its parent div?

- I would like both rows' styles are independent. I found a couple of solutions here, but if I change the height of the top row, the bottom row's style (e.g. margin) need to be changed along with it.
- I don't need to support old browsers. If it's standard, it's just okay.

Thanks!

Comment: If you don't specify a height for a div then it automatically fits the content, not the container. But if you know the top row is 100 and the containing div is 600, why not simply set the bottom row to height: 500?

Comment: I might frequently modify the height so I don't want to calculate the heights twice. Actually I think the dependency is not good.. Thanks for your comment though.

Comment: Why do you need to set the height of the second row - is it not enough to let it expand to the size of the content? If it is to do with styling the appearance, see my answer below

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I want the bottom div to automatically fill the rest of the parent div. I think this is a pretty common layout, but the solutions I found need to explicitly specify remaining 500px somewhere.

Comment: You need to edit your question to specify your full requirements, i.e. that the bottom div must be a fixed size and is required to scroll. All the answers supplied below don't take that into consideration because we didn't know thats what you wanted.

Comment: Also, while it may be a common layout, in most cases the CSS will specify the exact dimensions - there are usually other considerations such as padding, margins etc that affect the display & dimensions. Complicated layouts can have complicated CSS where it is very difficult to attempt to abstract the layout like this and particular positioning is usually achieved through specifying the dimensions for elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `display` property in CSS to fix this.

working [**EXAMPLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Bongs/ymLWq/)

HTML

```
<div id="a" style="width: 300px; height: 200px"> 
    <div id="b" style="height: 55%"> 
        top fixed-height row
    </div> 
    <div id="c" style=""> 
        bottom stretching row (the height should be 500px in this case.) 
    </div> 
</div> ​
```

CSS

```
#a
{
    border: 1px solid black;
    display:table;
}
#b
{
    background-color:red;
    display:table-row;
}
#c
{
    background-color:green;
    display:table-row;
}​
```

Comment: :) optimize the css to reduce the redundancy :)

Comment: @user1392013, FYI in Chrome, the code in the jsfiddle link results in exactly the same as my example did (the one that didn't take into account your additional requirements of adding a scrollbar). I know you're not concerned about older browsers but you do need to consider Chrome...

Answer (score 1):

For this case you can use preprocesor (like LESS):

```
@contHeight: 600px;
@topHeight: 100px;

div#containingdiv { 
    width: 800px; 
    height: @contHeight; 
    }
div#toprow { 
    width: 100%;
    height: @topHeight; 
    }
div#bottomrow {
    height: @contHeight - @topHeight; 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML and CSS are static not dynamic languages where you could perform calculations. You can only apply styles to each div individually because there is actually *no* dependency between the styles for each "row" div for you to determine the height of one based on the other.

However depending on what you are trying to achieve, it may be possible to style the containing div instead of the bottom div.

e.g. a very simplistic example where the top row should have a red background and bottom row have a yellow background, set the style for the containing div to have the appearance you require for the bottom div, and the top div will cover this appearance on the upper part of the container:

```
div#containingdiv { width: 800px; height: 600px; background:#ffff00; }
div#toprow { height: 100px; background:#ff0000; width 100%; }
div#bottomrow { }
```

Comment: That's because you didn't specify that the content would be bigger than the div and that you required a vertical scroll, so I didn't implement it to work that way! Like I said in my answer it depended on what you were trying to achieve. For an accurate solution you need to specify all your requirements

Answer (score 0):

I have just written a blog about HTML CSS layouts, the demo lets you manipulate most css settings via javascript.

http://attemptingawesomeness.blogspot.com.au/2012/05/css-html-layout-guide_13.html

http://attemptingawesomeness.blogspot.com.au/2012/05/ultimate-html-css-layout-demo.html